# What's the deal with glibc?

Tags: c, glibc

I know it's a standar c library, but I don't understand why c doesn't have a free library, not one that is lgpl. Is there any such library and if not, than that means every company/particular developer has to buy even the most basic libraries to develop commercial apps ?

Comment: If you don't like the license, write your own library under a different license...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proprietary applications using software library with LGPL license](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540128/proprietary-applications-using-software-library-with-lgpl-license)

Comment: The format "What is a C library with an unrestrictive license?" is acceptable on StackOverflow. For rants, open a blog.

Comment: If OP opened a new question in the acceptable form, there are plenty of answers. All of the BSDs, Android/Bionic, ... Also I believe glibc has some special exception as long as you're using it in unmodified form whereby the license is actually looser than the full strength of the LGPL. It's certainly acceptable for all but the most perverse proprietary software uses.

Answer (score 2):

> every company/particular developer has to buy even the most basic libraries to develop commercial apps ?

Well, they have to buy (or get for free) the compiler anyway, and libc comes with it.

Also, writing an universal C library is impossible, since `exit()`, `setjmp()`, etc. depend on the particular compiler and platform.

Comment: Yeah but still, if I am developing a commercial app by myself and I don't have money to buy licenses than what can I do ? this just restricts IT startups and just stop many potential programmers from creating a business.